# How to write route in angular with query parameters

Tags: angularjs

**URL**
http://localhost:9000/#/users/unlock?unlock_token=4QxKTxi4Qnxd7aMqtQUQ

**I tried to write as bellow..**

```
.state('unlock_user', {
        template: '...',
        controller:'UnlockUserCtrl',
        url: '/users/unlock?unlock_token',

        resolve: {
          loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load('scripts/controllers/loginController.js');
          }
        }
      })
```

Comment: This code should work, please explain what problem you're facing with it?

Answer (score 0):

```
.state('unlock_user', {
    template: '...',
    controller:'UnlockUserCtrl',
    url: '/users/unlock/:unlock_token',

    resolve: {
      loadMyFile: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
        return $ocLazyLoad.load('scripts/controllers/loginController.js');
      }
    }
  })
```

and for receiving in controller

```
$scope.unlock_token = $stateParams.unlock_token;
```

Comment: Where is query parameter in the URL?

Comment: /:unlock_token is query parameter in URL

Comment: I'd highly recommend you to check read [this article](http://www.ronstauffer.com/blog/understanding-a-url/) which explain what is query parameters.

Comment: have even try this?

Comment: LOL :D, No I'm talking blindly :D did you ever read what OP have asked for? and although OP's code should have work. Could you first explain why OP's code not working?

Comment: i know what is query parameters but instead  you can use a more RESTful URL like /users/unlock/:unlock_token

Comment: I thought you the one who asked a question but let the one who has questioned decide whether its working or not

Comment: Well sir, I'm not speaking with ego, I'm trying to keep answers upto the quality. Primarily this answer isn't explained why OP's way not working, afterwards you're asking OP to try other way around which doesn't make sense to me. This is my personal opinion.. Forgive me If I hurt your ego. please don't take it in other way.

Comment: It is always redirecting to login page not calling controller which i have assigned. if the code OK then may be cache issue.. trying to fix

Answer (score 0):

try the following in url

```
url: '/users?unlock=:unlock_token'
```

and receive in controller like this as above person told.